# Does MaterialModule include HttpModule?

Tags: angular-material2

Does **MaterialModule** in Angular Material 2 include `Http` providers by default?

I have created a service that injects `Http` from `@angular/http`. If I omit to import **HttpModule** in the main **AppModule**, there is no error and everything works as expected. If on the contrary, I remove the import of **MaterialModule**, then I get the error that there is no provider for `Http`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I import the whole **MaterialModule**, I can see that this is due to the automatic import of **MdIconModule**. It uses **HttpModule** internally in order to fetch Material Design icons.